# Css animation running slow

Tags: css

I have a portfolio site here:

http://benliger.webatu.com/

Im in the process of creating a mobile navigation menu and have decided to use CSS in the mobile view to animate the dropdown effect. My concern here is that the menu runs very "clunky" when you bring it down (animation jitters the menu down the page rather than running a smooth transition). It looks fine when its resized on a desktop browser but I was expecting a much smoother animation on mobile. The device im using for mobile is an HTC one mini so fairly new phone. The way its animating is just by adding and removing a class with a different margin-top. Can anyone tell me why its running so badly?

Code:

```
$('.mobile-menu-icon').click(function () {

$(".header-options").toggleClass("mobileheaderdown");
});


.header-options {
color:white;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 margin-left:0px;
list-style-type:none;
font-size:18px;
margin-top: -203px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.91);
width:100%;
text-align: center;
float: right;
}

.mobileheaderdown{
margin-top:2px !important;
}
```

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Is there a reason you're animating margin-top instead of using translate3d? You could leverage hardware acceleration w/ the latter

Comment: Code posted. No theres no reason Imjared could you advice how the code should look with translate 3D? I can test asap and check for a better result, I just assumed transition would have the same effect

Comment: also need the styles for `.mobileheaderdown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

margin-top is not an attribute that is accelerated for mobiles. You can do the safe effect by using transform:translate which is accelerated.

edit: Example:

```
.header-top {
  -webkit-transform:translate(0,-203px);
  -ms-transform:translate(0,-203px);
  transform:translate(0,-203px);
}
.header-top.mobileheaderdown {
  -webkit-transform:translate(0,0);
  -ms-transform:translate(0,0);
  transform:translate(0,0);
}
```

Comment: This has fixed the performance issue (once i added !important at the end of the mobile headerdownclass) but now the menu is getting nudged to the right when you first click the button on a mobile then keeps changing its margin by a few pixels left and right everytime you click the button... @scooterlord

Comment: the answer concerned the performance issues, not your actual design. What you should keep from it is that margin-top is NOT accelerated for mobile phones and you should find another method - the answer was just a suggestion.